# Whittaker model equation

Tags: functional-analysis, number-theory, representation-theory, automorphic-forms

This is from Cogdell and Piateski-Shapiro's paper *Derivative and L-functions for $GL_n$*.

Let $\lambda$ be a non-trivial $\psi$-Whittaker functional. The Whittaker model is defined as$W_v(g)=\lambda(\pi(g)v), v\in V_{\pi},g\in GL_n$. We know that $W_v\in W(\tau,\psi)$ iff there is a compact open subgroup $Y\subset U_n$ such that $$\int_Y W_v(py)\psi^{-1}(y)dy=0,\ \ p\in P_n.$$
I am confused why this can lead to: if writing $p=gu, g\in GL_{n-1}, u\in U_n$, we have
$$
\int_YW_v(guy) \psi^{-1}(y)dy=W_v(gu)\int_Y\psi(gyg^{-1})\psi^{-1}(y)dy.
$$
I understand it must be using the fact of $\lambda$ being a Whittaker functional, but I am still unable to show $W_v(guy)=W_v(gu)\psi(gyg^{-1}),$ frustrated..

Comment: Perhaps try emailing Cogdell? I had a look at that paper but was also unable to derive this equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just need to show $W_v(guy)=W_v(gu)\psi(gyg^{-1})$.

In fact, since $guyu^{-1}g^{-1}\in U_n$, and it is easy to verify $\psi(guyu^{-1}g^{-1})=\psi(gyg^{-1})$, hence
$$
W_v(guy)=W_v(guyu^{-1}g^{-1}gu)=\psi(guyu^{-1}g^{-1})W_v(gu)=W_v(gu)\psi(gyg^{-1}).
$$